# Do nice properties of MLE still hold in Classical Linear Regression Model?

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, inference

For simplicity, let's assume that we have the true DGP

$$y_i= \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \epsilon_i$$ where $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ $(i = 1,2,...,n)$

Assume that these following usual assumptions meet (for the classical linear regression model)

1. $y_i= \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \epsilon_i$ (linearity)
2. $x_i$ is ***deterministic***
3. $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $Cov[\epsilon_i, \epsilon_j] = 0$ for $i \neq j$ (normality, homoskedasticity and uncorrelatedness)

If we use Maximum Likelihood Estimation Method (MLE) to estimate $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, is it correct to state that the nice asymptotic properties as n approaches infinity (asymptotic efficiency, asymptotic consistency, ...) still hold for the MLE estimators of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$?

I believe that the answer is **no** because of the second assumption and, for example, $MSE[\hat{\beta}_{1MLE/OLS}] = \mathbb{V}[\hat{\beta}_{1MLE/OLS}] = \frac{\sigma^2}{Dev(x)}$ which implies there is no guarantee that $MSE[\hat{\beta}_{1MLE/OLS}]$ will approach 0 as n approaches infinity (sufficient but not necessary condition for convergence in probability), but I want to know whether or not it is correct.

Comment: What makes you think that with simple linear regression, the MLE estimators are any different from minimising the sum of squares of the residuals?

Comment: @Henry I want to know about the asymptotic properties of the estimators when n goes to infinity. Since the regressor is determinstic. 

I think there is no guarantee that MSE of the estimators, for example for MLE estimator of $\beta_1$, will go to 0 (sufficient but not necessary condition for convergence in probability - or here, consistency)

Comment: @edelweiss (Unless I've missed something, ) since the estimators depend on $\epsilon$, they are not deterministic even if $x$ is set manualy, for example in an experimental setting. Furthermore, there is no need for asymptotics in your setting: we get joint normality with the standard moments for all finite samples as well as optimality even in more general settings by the Gauss Markov theorem (also in finite samples).

Comment: Is this an example of non-MSE consistent but consistent (convergence in probability ) estimators? @JohnMadden. Anyway, thank you so much!

Comment: It depends on what additional $x_i$ you include as $n$ increases.  The variance of $\hat \beta_1$ is $\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2}$ which tends towards $0$ so long as the denominator increases without bound and you do not concentrate the additional $x_i$ around the existing $\bar x$.  So you are correct to worry if $x_1=1$ and $x_2=-1$ and all the other $x_i=0$: you will never mitigate the impact of $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$.  But this is not realistic: the point of expanding the sample for OLS is to see the impact of *different* values of $x_i$ on $y_i$.

Comment: Yes, now everything makes sense. Can you put it as an answer @Henry so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Requested in comments*

With simple linear regression, the MLE estimators the same as those from minimising the sum of squares of the residuals.

It depends on what additional $x_i$ you include as $n$ increases.  The variance of $\hat \beta_1$ is $\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2}$ which tends towards $0$ so long as the denominator increases without bound and you do not concentrate the additional $x_i$ around the existing $\bar x$.

So for example you are correct to worry if $x_1=1$ and $x_2=-1$ and all the other $x_i=0$: you will never mitigate the impact of $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ on $\hat \beta_1$.

But this is not realistic: the point of expanding the sample for OLS is to see the impact of *different* values of $x_i$ on $y_i$.